# Is it possible to embed binary data in a .NET assembly

Tags: c#, .net, embedded-resource, dotnetzip

Is it possible to embed binary data (as a resource, or by some other mean) in the C# assembly and then read the binary data from assembly during run-time and write it as a file.

I am making a DRM application and purpose is that the data must be hidden in the assembly as embedded resource, or a password protected ZIP file. So, I will try to embed the resource and if not possible then will look for a ZIP / UN-ZIP library with password protection to save DRM data.

I am writing a program in C# in which should have a binary data and it is added in the assembly during compile just like images, icons are added in assembly when we compile, and then when the assembly is executed by user then the binary data is read and saved as an external file.

Is it possible? then how to do it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes. If you are using [resources](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7k989cfy%28v=vs.90%29.aspx), you can include files too, which are represented as a byte array. Else you can include a file and set the `Build Action` to `Embedded Resource`, which include it as a resource too, which you can manually read.

```
public byte[] ExtractResource(Assembly assembly, string resourceName)
{
    if (assembly == null)
    {
        return null;
    }

    using (Stream resFilestream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(resourceName))
    {
        if (resFilestream == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        byte[] bytes = new byte[resFilestream.Length];
        resFilestream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);

        return bytes;
    }
}
```

Then use it like this:

```
byte[] bytes = this.ExtractResource( Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()
                                   , "Project.Namespace.NameOfFile.ext"
                                   );
```

Answer (score 5):

yeah, its possible. Just add the file in the project, Select the file, Go to property and select Embedded Resource in Build Action property.
Here's the code=

```
private Stream GetStream(string fileName)
    {
        var asm = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
        Stream stream = asm.GetManifestResourceStream("NameSpace." + fileName);
        return stream;
    }
```

> For clarification of sv88erik doubts-
>   as you can see in picture here, embedded resources are a part of the assembly itself and having a name as NameSpace.FileName

[image]

Comment: Rohit Prakash: IF you remove hardcoded namespace, you get +1 from me. Not good practice!

Comment: Give me a good reason why it should not be dynamic:) ?System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().EntryPoint.DeclaringType.Namespace

Comment: @sv88erik: What if it is included in another folder? Although I agree it is a good starting point *if* you are on the executing assembly.

Comment: @sv88erik The namespace can be found only using reflection? Not like Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().EntryPoint.DeclaringType.Namespace or something like this using Assembly class?

Comment: Patrick Hofman: Okay, but then it Should Be at least a constant ! http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/67982/is-it-ever-a-good-idea-to-hardcode-values-into-our-applications

Comment: @sv88erik, as you can see in ildasm. you can read more about Embedded resource at [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3089/Understanding-Embedded-Resources-in-Visual-Studio)

Comment: @sv88erik: Agree. This is more demo code than it is production worthy code. You can think of a lot of things that needs adjustment. It's just for the general idea.

Comment: The namespace can be found only using reflection "System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().EntryPoint.DeclaringType.Name‌​space" ? Not like Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().EntryPoint.DeclaringType.Namespace or something like this using Assembly class?

Comment: @Computer User: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.getexecutingassembly%28v=vs.110%29.aspx  Assembly is a in Reflection. If you have a type and x you can take x.getType().GetType, but not a nice idea! Use reflection or constant :)

Answer (score 1):

Background: When you build your application, the linked and embedded resource data is compiled directly into the application assembly (the .exe or .dll file).

To access the resources, use the class `Resources` contained in Resources.Designer.cs which is nested under the Resources.resx file in Solution Explorer. The Resources class encapsulates all your project resources into static readonly get properties. For example, a string resource “Bill” is accessed by `Properties.Resources.Bill`. You can access a Text file resource also as a `string` property. Binary files are referenced as properties of type `byte[]`.

1. Double-click Resources.resx. Select Add Resource/Add Existing File and scroll to the file you want to be included.
2. For binaries, the class Resources has a property of type `byte[]` that is named after the included file. Assume the file name to be MyApp.dll, then the property should have the name `MyApp`. You find the exact name in the code file Resources.Designer.cs nested under the Resources.resx file in Solution Explorer.
3. You can access the resource as `Properties.Resources.MyApp`. For example, you can save the resource as a binary file with `File.WriteAllBytes(PathAndName, Properties.Resources.MyApp);`.